# Post Comment using API

Tags: angular, api, post

I want to add a comment using **/posts/{id}/comments/add** I pass all the parameters like post_id, access_token and key and i get this results :

I have registered the app in stackapps and set the Placeholder

```
{
 "items": [
{
"owner": {
"reputation": 86,
"user_id": 8404155,
"user_type": "registered",
"accept_rate": 83,
"profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiPfj.png?s=128&g=1",
"display_name": "Samson",
"link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404155/samson"
},
"edited": false,
"creation_date": 1503046038,
"post_id": 8404155,
"body": "Example comment body"
}
],
"has_more": false,
"quota_max": 10000,
"quota_remaining": 9967
}
```

But the comment is not displayed in the **stackoverflow's comment section**!! Any answers regarding this will be of great help!Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Preview equal to **false** and the comment will be displayed in the Stackoverflow account.

Preview can be set to false [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-comment) to perform a test on the API.